# Reproducing an SQL result in an MDX Member

Tags: mdx

I'm having trouble with reproducing the same results in MDX as in SQL. The query in SQL that gives me a result I'm looking for goes like this:

```
SELECT        COUNT(Dim_Provider_Records_By_Day.ID) AS CompletedRecords
FROM            Dim_Provider_Records_By_Day INNER JOIN
                     Dim_Provider_Records ON Dim_Provider_Records_By_Day.RecordID = Dim_Provider_Records.ID
WHERE        Dim_Provider_Records.CompleteDateTime = Dim_Provider_Records_By_Day.PK_Date
```

Some of the things I've tried are below:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Count of Complete Records2] AS
COUNT(
FILTER([Dim Provider Records By Day].[ID].ALLMEMBERS, 
[Dim Provider Records By Day].[PK Date].Value = [Dim Provider Records By Day].[Complete Date Time].Value)
)

SELECT [Count of Complete Records2] ON COLUMNS FROM [DW DR Incomplete]
```

I've also tried the above using CURRENTMEMBER.VALUE, CURRENTMEMBER.NAME to no luck.

Basically, I want to get a count of all records in [Dim Provider Records By Day] where it's [PK Date] is equal to the [Complete Date Time]. Then the rest can be handled by the cube.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
COUNT(
FILTER([Dim Provider Records By Day].[ID].[ID].MEMBERS, 
[Dim Provider Records By Day].[PK Date].CurrentMember.Name = [Dim Provider Records By Day].[Complete Date Time].CurrentMember.Name)
)
```

As you are not interested in calculated members of the `ID` attribute, `Members` would be better than `AllMembers`.

To exclude the All member of the `ID` attribute in the set to filter, use the level `[Dim Provider Records By Day].[ID].[ID]` instead of the complete attribute hierarchy `[Dim Provider Records By Day].[ID]`.

And - assuming you have a relationship in your dimension from `ID` to `PK Date` as well as one to `Complete Date Time`, there should be unique `CurrentMember`s for both attributes per `ID` member, so that the filter condition is evaluated properly. Then you use the `Name` property to compare, as the `Value` property would be the value of the current measure - which is the measure that you are defining in your `WITH MEMBER` expression, which is NULL before the definition is finished, and thus would not provide any useful condition.